# Trying to trace performance issue with mysql2 on rails 2.3

Tags: performance, memory-leaks, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-2, mysql2

I have a strange problem with querying MySQL using ruby's `mysql2` adapter. I'm using `ruby-1.9.2-p290` and `mysql2-0.2.18.gem` (since `mysql2 >= 0.3` has issues with Rails 2.3.14, which I'm bound to). It works fine except for a specific query I'm performing on the DB - the query returns fine, but processing the results takes an unreasonable amount of time (compared to the old `ruby-mysql` gem I used before upgrading from ruby 1.8). The gist of the code looks something like this:

```
    require 'mysql2'

    client = Mysql2::Client.new({ 
        :host     => 'localhost',
        :username => 'minda',
        :password => 'sikriT',
        :database => 'testdb' 
    })

    # pretty elaborate query, utilizing
    # several joines and returning about
    # ~200,000 rows
    sql = "SELECT * FROM ..."

    # returns in reasonable time
    results = client.query(sql, :cast => false)

    # this takes about 3 minutes...
    # before the switch to 1.9/mysql2, this took
    # about 10 sec (which was reasonable,
    # considering I did some fairly 
            # processing inside the block)
    results.each do |row|
        # do nothing here!
    end
```

I've turned the code inside out and eventuall commented out everything inside the block, but can't see what could be causing this performance bottle neck.

I should note that I'm performing a lot of queries in this specific program using the same connection, and this is the only place that suffucates - possibly due to the large result-set. I ran this query directly on the DB server and nothing special happened. I also noticed this only happens when running this program in the context of Rails' `script/console`, or when calling it from inside a Rails application. When I run the above code in a simple IRB instance (no rails overhead), it runs fine -- which leads me to believe this might be a memory/GC issue.

Seems strange that `mysql2` (specifically, `Mysql2::Result`) will choke on large queries (client machine runs with QuadCore and 8GB RAM). Any thoughts on how to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly, it isn't actually choking on the query, but inside the block. Is that correct? If so, mysql isn't the problem.

Comment: That's correct, and what I meant. However, it exhibits this behavior inside the block that operates on `Mysql2::Result`. So I'm not sure how to better phrase this.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, turns out this was caused by my encoding setting in `environment.rb`, where I had:

```
Encoding.default_internal = 'UTF-8'
```

Apparently `Mysql2` was re-encoding all the strings in the result set, which obviously consumed plenty of resources (for a large result set).

Commenting that line out solved the issue.